# Can you disable the dynamic search in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: search, visual-studio-2015

I've only just upgraded after stubbornly hanging on to VS2010 for years.

When I hit CTRL-F to find, Visual Studio starts taking me to the location of what I'm typing as I'm typing it.  I often use search to see IF a word is in my file, so if I want to search for APPLE PIE it will take me to the word APPLE first and I'll lose my position-- and meanwhile APPLE PIE isn't in the file at all.  But I've still lost the place my cursor was before I searched.

Is there any way to disable this and make VS only search after I press enter or hit the button?  NOTE: I'm not using incremental search, I'm hitting CTRL-F.

Comment: Why not hit Ctrl+Shift+F?

Comment: I don't want to Find In Files, I just want to quickly search locally.  This workflow has been working for me with Visual Studio since about 1998.  I don't want to change baked in, ancient habits just because someone added a feature nobody ever asked for to Visual Studio.

Comment: Sounds like this is on the backlog to implement. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/60977