# How to disable the dynamic search as you type in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

In VS 2022 (and some earlier versions), when I press <kbd>CTRL-F</kbd> to find, the cursor moves to the next match as I type. I don't want it to move until I press enter key or the dialog arrow button. This is very disruptive, since it jumps around as I'm typing, and if the final string isn't found, I'm not somewhere else in the file.

I like the orange indicators in the side bar as I type; those can stay (or go away if it's tied to the setting).

Note: This is not incremental search. This is just Find in this file.

The question [Can you disable the dynamic search in Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60008516/292060) asked the same thing for VS 2019, and pointed to a now-closed GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/60977.
The GitHub thread shows it was implemented, but I don't see it. It's referencing a moveCursorOnType setting, which I can't find in VS 2022. It also dead ends ignoring someone saying it didn't work.

This is effectively a duplicate of that question, but this is for VS 2022, and that question never got an answer, so I didn't know how or whether to necro it.

Comment: Perhaps a slight workaround - if you change the search area to "Entire Solution", "Current Project", or "All Open Documents", it won't automatically move to the first occurrence of the word until you press enter to initiate the find.  Obviously the drawback is you are searching more than just the currently viewed file.  The orange indicators in the scrollbar will still appear though allowing you to manually move to the search results as you like.